# How map superclass in JDO with similar behaviour to @MappedSuperclass in JPA

Tags: jpa, orm, jdo, datanucleus

I need entities with identical set of base attributes but with different identity type and lifecycle.
Actualy I'm trying to implement bussiness audit with distinct entity. Embedded object is not option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<inheritance strategy="subclass-table"/>
```

would allow you to delay the binding of a superclass to the subclass table.

Or if you prefer annotations on the superclass:

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceStrategy.SUBCLASS_TABLE)
```

should do the trick.

See http://www.datanucleus.com/products/accessplatform_3_2/jdo/orm/inheritance.html#subclasstable

Answer (score 0):

watch out, you can't query a superclass if you have more than 1 subclass then, something like (in JQL):

```
SELECT id FROM some.superclass where creationstamp == :date"
```

does not work, as DataNucleus cannot resolve the table for multiple subclasses, new_table strategy works though